# Ignoring tags in XPATH using html agility pack

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, xpath, html-table

I am using the following code to parse html tables from an html file  into a dataset:

```
Public Function GetDataSet(html As String) As DataSet
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim htmldoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
htmldoc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim tables = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr") _
                                 .GroupBy(Function(x) x.ParentNode)
For i As Integer = 0 To tables.Count - 1
    Dim rows = tables(i).ToList()
    ds.Tables.Add(String.Format("Table {0}", i))
    Dim headers = rows(0).Elements("th").Select(Function(x) x.InnerText.Trim).ToList()
    For Each Hr In headers
        ds.Tables(i).Columns.Add(Hr)
    Next
    For j As Integer = 1 To rows.Count - 1
        Dim row = rows(j)
        Dim dr = row.Elements("td").Select(Function(x) x.InnerText.Trim).ToArray()
        ds.Tables(i).Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
Next
Return ds
End Function
```

and it works fine. But When There are a Tag placed inside the `<Table>` Tag before `<tr>` tag the table is not parsed

**Simple Example:**

`<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
    <div>Contents:</div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th> <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td> <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td> <td>22</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th> <th>Column2</th> <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td> <td>aa</td> <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td> <td>bb</td> <td>bbb</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
       <div>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th> <th>Column2</th> <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td> <td>aa</td> <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td> <td>bb</td> <td>bbb</td>
        </tr>
       </div>
    </table>
</body>
</html>`

In This Example only the first table is parsed.

My question is how to ignore any tag between `<Table>` tag and `<tr>` tag in the following line of code:

```
Dim tables = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr") _
                             .GroupBy(Function(x) x.ParentNode)
```

and all the tables will be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `//` to select from all descendants:

```
Dim rows = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr");
```

Also based on your requirement, it seems it's better to group the result based on the first ancestor `table`, because the parent of `tr` may be a `tbody` or `thead` and you need to group rows in tables:

```
Dim tables = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr") _
                    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Ancestors("table").First())
```

Comment: To learn more about XPath you can take a look at [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).